# Filtering Features Graphically on QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter, gui

I currently filter QGIS features using expressions. However, as I need to handle a large number of variables this can be tedious. Is there a plugin or any other method to filter features of a given layer graphically where I can enter values for given variables as text or using a slider?

Comment: What do you mean by filtering? The "Filter" option from the Layers panel context menu? And what is your desired end-result? [Rule-based rendering](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#rule-based-renderer) works well in combination with the aforementioned Filter function. The [Select features by value](https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html#select-features-by-value) tool is also quite similar to what you describe.

Comment: I think OP's issue with Filter and Rule-based rendering is the use of expressions (even if basic) which can be error-prone or tedious when multiple variables are involved. Select features by value is somewhat limited in its scope. I think OP has an existing expression, but wants a simple GUI to just edit the input variables without needing to edit the expression itself. I understand as it's fair number of clicks to edit the filter, find the variable to change, edit it, close - rather than just have a panel with 4 sliders for example.

Comment: If I have understood right though, that sounds like a solution that would need a custom design - some kind of plugin that connects to a filter expression by way of special variables or something. OP, if your issue is that the variables in the expression are hard to find and edit, try restructuring your expression using `with_variable()` so that all the variables are at the top and each on their own line for quick editing.